# input validation using ng-blur (change background color if input is wrong)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, validation

I have this input type number. It accepts characters like '-', '.', and null apart from the numbers.

Currently, it accepts these below values too.

```
1) '.3343..343.33' 
2) '-0.45---.5'
```

It should not accept above values as they are not a number. I am trying to put validation to it so that once user exits that input field after entering '.3343..343.33', it highlights the input field with background color red. So that it will notify user that input entered is not accepted.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this using ng-blur. I saw one using ng-blur and ng-model-options too. Is there a easy way to achieve this sort of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method , its working

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.value = true;
  
  $scope.blurT = function(){
   // $scope.value = true;
   var calc = Number($scope.inputValue) - Number($scope.inputValue);
  if(calc == 0){
     $scope.value = true;
    console.log(calc);
  } else { 
    $scope.value = false;
   
  }
    
  }
  $scope.checkClass = function(){
  var value = ($scope.value===true ? 'success':'error');
   return value;
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.error {
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-class="{'error': value == false}"  ng-model="inputValue" ng-blur="blurT()">
   {{value}} 
  </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: @rejs- i am trying to get it working in input type = 'number' . this is input type text which you have used. Do you have it for number ?

Comment: @Patrick , I updated the code with input type='number' in code snippet. its working fine  If you want previous code with directive use this plunker link 
http://plnkr.co/edit/YV5fnE0TVOtxRLF2Bpfb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically assigns contextual classes `ng-valid` & `ng-invalid` to form fields that pass/fail validation. You can assign styles to these selectors to have visual validation signals. There are a number of other classes as well.

You can set up the validation with the HTML `pattern='<regular_expression'` attribute. However in this case there seems to be at least 2 limitations to that:

- browsers don't like applying regular expressions to number fields (to fix this I switched to `ng-pattern` in the example, which is handled entirely by Angular)
- number field models don't update after typing a decimal point until another character is entered (so typing `25.` and stopping isn't invalid)

Either of these can be fixed by switching to a regular `type='text'` field, but then you lose the special UI number controls like the spinner and the number keyboard on mobile.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('main', function ($scope) {$scope.myNumber = 5;});
```

```css
input.ng-invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
    background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="main">
<form>
  Enter a number:
  <input type="number" ng-pattern="/^\d*$/" ng-model="myNumber"> = {{myNumber}}
</form>
</div>
```